# mySQL query or and not

Tags: mysql

I have this query

`Select ID, title,tags from items where ID != 305096 AND title LIKE '%airplane%' or title LIKE '%car%' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20`

I want to get all the results except where ID == 305096. I also tried to use '<>' but none works.
Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Use the brackets to wrap the rest of the where condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select ID, title,tags from items where ID != 305096 AND (title LIKE '%airplane%' or title LIKE '%car%') ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Have to group with parentheses:

```
Select ID, title,tags from items where ID != 305096 AND (title LIKE '%airplane%' or title LIKE '%car%') ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some parens around your logic like this:

```
Select ID, title,tags from items 
where (ID != 305096) AND (title LIKE '%airplane%' or title LIKE '%car%') 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20
```